# Add icons to Sencha Touch 2.3.1

Tags: css, extjs, icons, sencha-touch

Hi i'm new to sencha touch and using sencha touch 2.3.1. So i want to add my own icon to my app. but still could not find a path to add my icon. please help me.

Comment: Could you please be more specific ?. Is it an app icon or something to show inside your view ?

Comment: I you want to add icons inside your app you have to use iconfonts: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/guide/theming-section-IconFonts or see this blog entry: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/guide/theming-section-IconFonts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taka a look at this instruction. I have spent several hours studying official documentation and of no success, but this one helped me http://bruno.tavares.me/sencha-touch/adding-custom-font-icons-to-sencha-touch-2-2/

Answer (score 2):

I've recently created this [new tool](https://github.com/tohagan/sencha-ico-moon) that will help you to prepare icons for your Sencha Touch apps.  The README explains the steps for creating icons at the Ico Moon web site and converting the Ico Moon project for use in Sencha Touch.